# Postgres cannot replace trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function to automatically create a row in one table when there is an insert in another row, I already created it before but it was wrong and now I can't create it again

this is my sql code

```
create or replace function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger as
$$
  begin
    insert into public.profiles (user_id, first_name, last_name)
    values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'first_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'last_name');
    return new;
  end;
$$
language plpgsql security definer;

create or replace trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row
    execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

I am getting this error

```
Failed to validate sql query: syntax error at or near "trigger"
```

Comment: `or replace` option was added in Postgres 14. Drop the trigger (if exists) manually or upgrade to Postgres 14+.

Comment: You forgot to disclose your version of Postgres. Get it with `SELECT version();`